# Infinite light using a true one way mirror

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, reflection, light-emitting-diodes

Imagin this, a triangular prism with one way mirrors on each face of it and with a light source on the inside and out, it seems normal, right? But, now the light turns off, will the light keep bouncing on the inside? And will it basically give if a source of energy that lasts so long? Remember this is a true one way mirror.

Comment: If they existed, yes, they could store a lot of energy. by definition.

Comment: "Light source on the inside and out". What does this mean?

Comment: The logic in this question is out of this world

Comment: There's a minor Problem: for infinite light, there is quite some input energy needed. But we can use mass also. When we just start with using up the visible universe, we must take great care not to burn your own matter too early, so you can observe it. (Oh, and I honestly do not care what we use next. Maybe more universes? Or some gods?)  Take a note that using physical infinity comes with quite many drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a light bulb with nothing around it. It gives of energy as long as it stays lit. If it stayed lit an infinite time, it would give off an infinite amount of energy.

This energy has to come from somewhere. A battery, a power cord, or some such. The point is you would have to put infinite energy in to get infinite energy out.

Now surround the light bulb with a mirror that is ordinary, aside from being a perfect reflector. The light cannot get out. Every time it hits a mirror, it is reflected back. So the energy given inside the mirrors grows and grows as long as the bulb is on.

There is no such thing as a perfect mirror. Real mirrors always absorb at least a little light. Also the bulb inside is not a mirror. So in reality, some energy would be absorbed on each bounce. The mirror and bulb would get hot.

Hot things glow, so energy would get out that way. Or hot things melt.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - Assume the one way mirrors are orientated to reflect to the inside of the prism  :-). Only an outside source is needed to light the inside of the prism. Also the inside light would absorb all the light energy over time.

Second - Assume light is energy of many electromagnetic frequencies. They will eventually clash at perfect opposites ( destructive interference ) and over time cancel each other out ( but where does the energy go ? Check Poynting vectors).

Third - Assume a true mirror, the prism will not radiate any energy in any way, unless the true mirror only reflects light energy then non-visible forms of energy will escape ( as per second point ).

Lastly - Assume that light energy cannot change form, then the prism will reflect light internally indefinitely AND absorb any new light.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

If both the sources are switched off and we assume that there is no external source anywhere, the prism will be able to store the energy supplied till the sources are switched (google why diamonds sparkle!). That is it, it will store that energy. It will will not act as source of energy, it just traps the light.